# CLI tool to upload to CTAN

Tags: tools, package-writing, ctan

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`ctanupload`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctanupload)

`sty2dtx` and `ctanify` are useful tools to prepare clean packages to CTAN. Is there also a tool to upload the package from a terminal?

Comment: I made once a `Makefile` which called `firefox` with the complete form data except the file name as part of the URL, but it doesn't work any longer. Might be caused by changes in the CTAN upload form or maybe by the new Firefox version. However, it then didn't worked in my tests with other browser as well.

Comment: @Martin: oh my! Wouldn't curl do the job?

Comment: It looks like it would. Also a Perl script using a WWW library would also be an option. It then could display the data first before sending it. I don't think the CTAN admins woudl be happy to get a lot of faulty uploads ;-)

Comment: @Martin: indeed, we would need to check stuff before uploading. Ideally, I think the script would call `ctanify` to make sure to upload something clean, and parse the archive to get the author, package name, description, version, etc. It would then ask for confirmation before sending.

Comment: Parsing the archive would be cumbersome and error-prone. The script should be called with the correct data. The whole thing including `ctanify` can then be part of a Makefile.

Comment: If the requirement is from the terminal rather than programmatic then would `lynx` or similar suit the purpose?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Robin Fairbairns is pretty laid-back about upload issues. (Usually, using some form of automation means less rather than more issues: I do a _lot_ of CTAN updates, and all of the building is done using scripts so I don't forget files/line endings/...)

Comment: @mas: the idea is to type a single command (or even put it in a Makefile) to upload packages, not to fill forms in lynx or links2.

Comment: related project: `github action` at https://github.com/paolobrasolin/ctan-submit-action

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 2011/09/07**: Now on CTAN: [`ctanupload`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctanupload), including [PDF manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/support/ctanupload/ctanupload.pdf).

I had now a look on how to code a script to handle the WWW form upload and went with Perl and the `WWW::Mechanize` library. The following script allows to upload a contribution to CTAN. The form fields can be provided using `--<name>=<value>` or using environment variables, which simplifies the use in Makefiles. I also implemented an interactive mode and error checking for the input.
I uploaded the script itself to CTAN as `ctanupload`.

#### Usage:

See [README](http://mirror.ctan.org/support/ctanupload/README) file on CTAN.

#### Script:

Available on CTAN [ctanupload.pl](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/ctanupload/ctanupload.pl) or over the source code repository: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/ctanupload

Comment: Hats off to you, Martin! The `Mechanize` library is awesome!

Comment: Great! Would you like to write a post on the TeX.SX blog about it?

Comment: @Martin: Very clever, but I'm left wondering if this is actually easier than filling out the form :-)

Comment: @Joseph — I know I would certainly prefer to use a script! I'm looking forward to using this.

Comment: @Joseph: Directly from the command line it isn't easier, but you can configure many constant things using a script or Makefile, so you only have to add the summary and announcement text.

Comment: @MartinScharrer ctanupload stopped working a few months ago. The guys over at CTAN say it needs to be adapted. Would you do it, or shall I fork/send you a PR somewhere?