# How to upload a tds.zip file to CTAN

Tags: ctan, contribute

From the `ctanify` documentation (great tool, by the way) I got the impression that just including a *.tds.zip file when doing a CTAN upload is sufficient. Well, obviously not, since the tds.zip file just ended up on the scrapheap instead of http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib.

Excerpt from the `ctanupload` log:

```
# 2011-10-09 19:50:46
contribution = caption
version = 3.2c
...
# caption.tar.gz (5089187):
# drwxrwxr-x axel/axel         0 2011-10-09 19:49 caption/
...
# -rw-rw-r-- axel/axel      1991 2011-10-09 19:49 caption/caption.ins
# -rw-rw-r-- axel/axel      2276 2011-10-09 19:49 caption/README
# -rw-rw-r-- axel/axel   2568077 2011-10-09 19:49 caption.tds.zip


# Response:

# 
# Your upload to CTAN has succeeded.
# ==================================
...
```

Do I have to do a separate CTAN upload for the tds.zip file? Or did I miss something?

I have searched for this topic on SX, and I'm aware of http://dante.ctan.org/upload, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-uploads, [How to upload my packages or document classes to CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23892/how-to-upload-my-packages-or-document-classes-to-ctan), [CLI tool to upload to CTAN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27244/cli-tool-to-upload-to-ctan), and [How can I contribute to CTAN?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/854/how-can-i-contribute-to-ctan), but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually upload it using `ctanify` and (in the past) the using the normal web upload form or (now) using my `ctanupload` script. I wondered as well where the TDS ZIP files landing up, but I found them all under the mentioned http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib directory or under http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/ if your package isn't under `/macros/latex/contrib`, like e.g. TikZ related packages.

I checked the package entry at http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/caption which explicitly lists the TDS ZIP file in the 'On CTAN:' line, but it is missing there. I double-checked the daily XML DB dump file I have and there is currently no TDS ZIP listed for `caption`.

Maybe your file still needs some time to appear there. They need to be placed there manually by the CTAN crew and then it takes the usual short delay until all servers and mirrors have it. You could also ask about them by sending a mail to `ctan@dante.de`. They might have accidentally forgot the TDS ZIP file.
You could also consider uploading it again to [DANTE](http://dante.ctan.org/upload.html) and ask explicitly for it to be placed on CTAN.

Comment: I just send a request to ctan@dante.de. I'll keep you informed...

Comment: ...Rainer Schöpf has just answered that he accidently installed the caption.tds.zip with a wrong file name. So just including the tds.zip file seems indeed to be sufficient.

Comment: ...and Robin Fairbairns has answered, that they will put that question/answer into the next faq release. Great!